# How to Initialise class properties using inquirer js?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inquirer

```
class Example {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = this.getId();
    }
    getId() {
        inquirer
            .prompt({
                message: "Enter id?",
                type: "input",
                name: "employeesId",
            })
            .then((answer) => (this.id = answer.employeesId));
    }
}

const testExample = new Example();
testExample.getId()
console.log(testExample.id); // <-- expected to log the id after user has entered it, instead returns undefined
```

So I'm new to OOP and just would like to understand why this won't work, any help would be appreciated.

A work around with explanation would also be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1st You didn't called `getId()`, also you need to return `Promise` from `getId()`, Because `inquirer.prompt()` return Promise ( It take time ) , At last you need to wait until `testExample.id` get modified, So first  add return so it look like: `return inquirer`, Then call `testExample.getId().then(() => console.log(testExample.id))`

Comment: Unless required by a third party package, please switch to using async/await, code is much cleaner and you could reduce the coding lines in this to at least half.

Comment: "*How to Initialise class properties using inquirer js?*" - not at all. The prompt for values is not the responsibility of that class, and definitely not of the constructor. Get the values first, then construct the instance afterwards, using constructor parameters. See also [general advice on doing asynchronous stuff in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686979/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

It takes a while for the `then()` callback to get called.  But when you do this:

```
testExample.getId()
console.log(testExample.id);
```

You aren't waiting for the `inquirer` to finish and set the `id`.  There's no way to wait for it right now because `getId()` is a `void` method.  It needs to return a `Promise`.

The best way to do this is with `async`/`await` syntax.  If you make `getId()` an `async` method then that means it will return a `Promise` that you can `await`.

It is not possible to definitely set the id to a `number` in the constructor because the constructor cannot be asynchronous.  You can either have `this.id` be a `Promise` which resolves to a `number` or you can have it start out as `undefined` and then get set to a number once the `inquirer` is finished.

It looks like you are currently accepting an `id` as an argument to the constructor but you don't use it, so I'm not sure what's going on there.

With `this.id` as maybe `undefined`:

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
    }
    async getId() {
        const answer = await inquirer
            .prompt({
                message: "Enter id?",
                type: "input",
                name: "employeesId",
            });
        this.id = answer.employeesId;
    }
}

const testExample = new Example();
await testExample.getId();
console.log(testExample.id);
```

With `this.id` as a `Promise`:

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.id = this.getId();
    }
    async getId() {
        const answer = await inquirer
            .prompt({
                message: "Enter id?",
                type: "input",
                name: "employeesId",
            });
        return answer.employeesId;
    }
}

const testExample = new Example();
const id = await testExample.id;
console.log(id);
```

Comment: Unless this is a UI class, I wouldn't do either.

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't either, but I'm trying to answer the question as it's presented.